# Typescript compile error: 'declare' modifier not allowed for code already in ambient context

Tags: typescript

I use the typescript definition file for breeze in my project (breeze.d.ts). When I compile my project, I got an error line 216:

`'declare' modifier not allowed for code already in an ambient context.`

If I simply delete `declare` it compiles successfully.

Does anyone experiencing the same problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It happens when you are inside a declare section e.g.:

```
declare module Mod{
    declare var x;
}
```

Fix is the remove the inner declare keyword:

```
declare module Mod{
    var x;
}
```

So: The original typescript definition file you have is incorrect for the latest version of typescript.

Answer (score 9):

I got this error because I added ';' at the end of lines inside a declare module block:

```
declare module SomeModule {
    export function someFunction():any; <--- remove the ';'
    export function anotherFunc():any
}
```